# Finding the maximum volume of a box bounded by a plane?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, 3d, volume

The box is in the first octant, and one corner is located at the origin while the opposite corner is located on the plane $x+2y+3z=6$.

My approach was to write the volume as $F(x, y, z) = xyz$, substitute $6-2y-3z$ for $x$, and find the maximum of $F$. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: I certainly would give it a try. Then do you know how to go by partial derivatives and setting them equal to zero?

Comment: @imranfat Yes, I was able to get a nice system of equations where I was able to factor out one variable from each equation, which left me with two linear equations of two unknowns. I got y=1 and z=2/3

Comment: Maybe you could post these equations then we can see if it makes all sense. It doesn't seem like an undoable problem

Comment: @imranfat well after setting the partial derivatives equal to zero I got $0=z(6-4y-3z)$ and $0=y(6-2y-6z)$. Using the zero product property, $6-4y-3z=0$ and $6-2y-6z=0$, which is the system of two linear equations of two variables which is easy to solve

Comment: It seems ok with me,but is your final answer consistent with what you have in the book? I can see from your 2 equations that both y and z are positive which is expected...